# How to run asynchronous tasks synchronous?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm developing an app with the following node.js stack: Express/Socket.IO + React. In React I have DataTables, wherein you can search and with every keystroke the data gets dynamically updated! :)

I use Socket.IO for data-fetching, so on every keystroke the client socket emits some parameters and the server calls then the callback to return data. This works like a charm, but it is not garanteed that the returned data comes back in the same order as the client sent it.

To simulate: So when I type in 'a', the server responds with this same 'a' and so for every character.

I found the async module for node.js and tried to use the queue to return tasks in the same order it received it. For simplicity I delayed the second incoming task with setTimeout to simulate a slow performing database-query:

**Declaration:**

```
const async = require('async');
var queue = async.queue(function(task, callback) {

if(task.count == 1) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     callback();
     }, 3000);
   } else {
     callback();
   }
}, 10);
```

**Usage:**

```
socket.on('result', function(data, fn) {
    var filter = data.filter;

      if(filter.length === 1) { // TEST SYNCHRONOUSLY
          queue.push({name: filter, count: 1}, function(err) {
            fn(filter);
            // console.log('finished processing slow');
          });


      } else {
        // add some items to the queue
        queue.push({name: filter, count: filter.length}, function(err) {
          fn(data.filter);
          // console.log('finished processing fast');
        });
      }

    });
```

But the way I receive it in the client console, when I search for *abc* is as follows:

ab -> abc -> a(after 3 sec)

I want it to return it like this: a(after 3sec) -> ab -> abc

My thought is that the queue runs the setTimeout and then goes further and eventually the setTimeout gets fired somewhere on the event loop later on. This resulting in returning later search filters earlier then the slow performing one.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Why dont you use `debounce & throttle` on a UI site? I think it's a good way of fixing your problem.

Comment: @TheReason But with that approach you specify a maximum number of times a function can be called over time, if I'm right? But how would this be a good solution if you don't know the duration of a response?

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a few comments, which might help clear up your understanding of async calls:

1. Using "timeout" to try and align async calls is a bad idea, that is not the idea about async calls. You will never know how long an async call will take, so you can never set the appropriate timeout.
2. I believe you are misunderstanding the usage of queue from async library you described. The documentation for the queue can be found here.

Copy pasting the documentation in here, in-case things are changed or down:

> Creates a queue object with the specified concurrency. Tasks added to the queue are processed in parallel (up to the concurrency limit). If all workers are in progress, the task is queued until one becomes available. Once a worker completes a task, that task's callback is called.

The above means that the queue can simply be used to priorities the async task a given worker can perform. The different async tasks can still be finished at different times.

**Potential solutions**

There are a few solutions to your problem, depending on your requirements.

1. You can only send one async call at a time and wait for the first one to finish before sending the next one
2. You store the results and only display the results to the user when all calls have finished
3. You disregard all calls except for the latest async call

In your case I would pick **solution 3** as your are searching for something. Why would you use care about the results for "a" if they are already searching for "abc" before they get the response for "a"?

This can be done by giving each request a timestamp and then sort based on the timestamp taking the latest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used timeout to simulate a slow db-query returning some data. So with that queue you can't run tasks synchronously? Solution 3 is indeed the ideal solution, but I don't get my head around on how to implement it. I now perform SELECT query's on each keystroke, but then I have to save each request somewhere, still in queue? And then taking the last to query or?

Comment: Correct, everything in the queue is run async. It is a tool which can be used to ensure you only use the capacity of one worker. 

Without the full code it is difficult to give you an example, but you either send up a timestamp or retrieve a timestamp from the server indicating when the query was send (preferred from the server).
Then when it is returned you have to check:
    `if(myObject.Timestamp < receivedObject.Timestamp)
   {
       myObject = receivedObject
    }`
Where myObject is your current displayed search result and the receivedObject is whatever search result you received

Comment: firstly I want to thank you a lot. Your information has led to a solution which I implemented and it works. Instead of using timestamps for the sake of simplicity, I use a counter. I check if the client's state counter(which is the last) is equal to the receiving response's counter. You can see the solution in my original post. It is not the most ideal situation now, because unneeded data still gets sent to the client, but it ignores it. But I think it is acceptable.  Do you have an idea on how to keep unneeded data at the server? Lastly, what did you mean with your second solution?

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify solution 2. Thanks for pointing tha tout. 

To keep "unneeded" data sent to the client a simple solution would be for the server to check if has already received other async calls. For instance, by storing your "counter" or adding a counter to each call it receives. Then before returning to the client, the server checks if a call with a higher "counter" has been returned already, if that is the case, it aborts the request.

Comment: However! This might give you issues on the client side, as the request it sends fails. 

The easiest way of doing it, is simply to let the client deal with it, which I believe would also be the nicest solution.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I marked your answer. I also thought that dealing with this on the client is the nicest solution, because you can't for example abort db querys when there are newer requests on the server. So there is not much of performance to win here.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Server:

```
exports = module.exports = function(io){
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('result', function(data, fn) {

    var filter = data.filter;
    var counter = data.counter;

      if(filter.length === 1 || filter.length === 5) { // TEST SYNCHRONOUSLY
          setTimeout(function() {
            fn({ filter: filter, counter: counter}); // return to client
          }, 3000);

      } else {
          fn({ filter: filter, counter: counter}); // return to client
      }

    });

  });


}
```

Client:

```
export class FilterableDataTable extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
        endpoint: "http://localhost:3001",
        filters: {},
        counter: 0
    };

    this.onLazyLoad = this.onLazyLoad.bind(this);
}

onLazyLoad(event) {
    var offset = event.first;

    if(offset === null) {
        offset = 0;
    }

    var filter = ''; // filter is the search character

    if(event.filters.result2 != undefined) {
        filter = event.filters.result2.value;

    }

    var returnedData = null;

    this.state.counter++;

        this.socket.emit('result', { 
            offset: offset,
            limit: 20,
            filter: filter,
            counter: this.state.counter
        }, function(data) {
            returnedData = data;

         console.log(returnedData);

            if(returnedData.counter === this.state.counter) {

                console.log('DATA: ' + JSON.stringify(returnedData));
            } 
}
```

This however does send unneeded data to the client, which in return ignores it. Somebody any idea's for further optimizing this kind of communication? For example a method to keep old data at the server and only send the latest?